# What is the relation between beta-carotene molecule length and orange light wavelength?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, physical-chemistry, molecules

[β-Carotene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-Carotene) is a orange-red organic molecule present in carrots and other living organisms.

[image: β-Carotene molecular representation]

From the number of atoms in the carbon chain, I assume that the length of the molecule is only a few nanometers (couldn't find an exact measure anywhere).

The visible light wavelength, on the other hand, is at the order of hundreds of nanometers, with red-orange around 500-600 nm.

So how do these two different measures interact, so as to make β-Carotene the color we see it?

Comment: You are thinking of scattering (why the sky is blue) which is not the same as molecular absorption/emission (why most things have colors). The absorption/emission is mainly due to the energy levels of the molecular species. Read up on spectroscopy, and you will start to understand better what Joseph H also posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall size of the β-Carotene molecule, C$_{40}$H$_{56}$ and its relation  to the wavelength of light in the visible spectrum, does not determine the color of it. What does however, is the properties of the chemical bonds that make up the molecule.

The long chain of alternating conjugated double bonds$^1$ is what gives the orange color of β-carotene, and other chemicals called [carotenoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carotenoid).

This conjugated chain in carotenoids means that they absorb  the green/blue part (higher energy, lower wavelength) of the visible spectrum. So β-carotene appears orange, because the red/yellow colors (lower energy, higher wavelength) are actually reflected back to us.

But why?

$\beta$-carotene is a highly conjugated molecule. This means the electrons in the bond are highly delocalised. The more electron delocalization that exists, then the smaller will be the gap between the highest energy [$\pi$ bonding molecular orbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_bond) and the lowest energy $\pi$ [anti-bonding molecular orbital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibonding_molecular_orbital). The promotion of an electron will therefore take less energy in $\beta$-carotene.

Less energy will mean lower frequency, higher wavelength, light will get absorbed. $\beta$-carotene absorbs light throughout the blue-V part of the EM spectrum, mostly in the visible region which is about between about $(400 -500)nm$ that peaks at about $470 nm$.

It's also important to note that if a particular color is absorbed from white light, whatever color your eye sees is done by the mixing of all the other wavelengths of light, and this is called its [complementary color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors). In $\beta$-carotene, the situation is more complicated because of the absorption of such a range of wavelengths. However, as stated, as the peak absorption runs from blue-V, then the color we would see will be the compliment of that to where yellow runs into red. One again, this would be orange.

$^1$ Conjugated double bonds in a molecule, means single and double bonds alternate along the molecule. This enables the electrons to be completely delocalized over the whole molecule and can therefore be shared by many atoms.

Comment: But why exactly does it absorb the green/blue part and reflect the red/yellow? How can we compare it with molecules of different colors (hemoglobin, hemocyanin and chlorophyll come to mind, though a linear hydrocarbon would make a better comparison)? Can we predict the color of a molecule from the molecular diagram?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. I will add that explanation to my answer today if time permits. Cheers.

Comment: Remembering you, if you can.

Comment: Hey Rodrigo. Thanks for the reminder. I’ll get onto it sometime today. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct relation between the length of beta-carotene and its absorption spectrum.
Read these two references:
http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/GenChem2/A7/3.html
http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.jlce.20150302.01.html